# Force Copy Task in Azure DevOps to retain folder structure

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to move my team over to Azure DevOps and we're hitting a slight snag with the Copy Task.

Currently the task takes all project files and chucks them into a single drop folder, however, I need it to retain the original folder structure:

```
- Project 1
  - bin
      - Release
          - **
```

As stated, it currently just does:

```
- drop
  - **
```

Appreciate any help as I'm not familiar with DevOps at this stage:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should expand the `Advanced` section and make sure the `Flatten Folders` checkbox is not checked:

[image]

Comment: Yes, It will flatten all the folder structures, including the folder under the `bin` folder. Is there any way to flatten the folder structures before `\bin` folder, but keep folder structures under the `\bin` folder?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Haven't tried it myself, to be honest, but I would not expect it to be that advanced...

Comment: Yes, as test, I agree with you.